# Xamarin & Caliburn.Micro, advice needed

Tags: c#, xamarin, caliburn.micro, portable-class-library, .net-standard

Here I come today for an advice. For so many years I used **WPF** for my desktop applications, with the wonderful **Caliburn.Micro** by my side.

Today, I have a **Xamarin** app to create and I see that the best way to build a cross-platform app is to use the *new* **.NET Standard** library above **Portable Class Library**. I understand that, but unfortunately, Caliburn.Micro is not ready for that (for a profesionnal app).

So the question is, would it be really really bad to choose **PCL** for getting the **Caliburn.Micro** compatibility, or should I look to another MVVM framework? I see one is shipped with **Xamarin**, so maybe it's the good choice?

Comment: Use .NET Standard. Prism is not bad and also available for WPF. (if you'd like to learn a new framework).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already know PRISM, but there is not the same (very usefull) tools in that framework (ie attaching view model function on every event without the need of command).

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily a bad thing to start with PCL. You will be able to switch to .net Standard with CM 4.0 is released. This is the situation I'm actually in. I'm temporarily stuck with PCL. I'm sure PRISM is great but I have a lot of skills with CM and I tried to use Prism at first due to the .net Standard issue. I couldn't get over the fact that in Prism I was going to have to manually create Command objects for every method call on the VM so I went back to CM for it's Action syntax.  In my opinion just hold out for CM 4.0.

Comment: Thank you Sean, very usefull answer ! I'm coming with more precisions, I'm not building the app from scratch, I'm actually improve and maintain an existing app created with PCL and.. without any MVVM in it :'( I will add CM and improve the app maintanability, then wait for CM4. Thank you :-)